# Lumen 5.5 Socialite Providers doesn't works with setConfig()

Tags: php, lumen, laravel-socialite, lumen-5.4

I use **Laravel Socialite Providers** (https://socialiteproviders.github.io/) to login user on Lumen 5.5 API.
**setConfig()** method, to force config, doesn't works for me...

Here below, my error and my code. The problem is that I do not know why I have this error.

**Display Error:**

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteManager::formatConfig() must be of the type
>   array, null given, called in
>   /home/vagrant/www/project1/api.website.app/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/SocialiteManager.php
>   on line 125

**PHP code:**

```
$clientId = env('TWITTER_KEY');
$clientSecret = env('TWITTER_SECRET');
$redirectUrl = env('TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI');
$additionalProviderConfig = [];
$config = new SocialiteConfig($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl, $additionalProviderConfig);

return Socialite::with('twitter')->stateless()->setConfig($config)->redirect();
```

Comment: I see an error, but I don't see a question...  I'm assuming you want some help figuring out *why* you get the error?

Comment: Excuse me, I have indeed forgotten the question ... I edit the issue immediately.

Comment: have u found solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure `services` configuration first! Create a `services.php` file inside `config` folder (you may create this one if you don't have it already).

File `services.php`

```
return [
    'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_KEY'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_SECRET'),
        'redirect' => env('TWITTER_REDIRECT_URI'),
    ]
];
```

Your code should be like this:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

// You may not this one, read below explanation
app()->configure('services');

return Socialite::with('twitter')->stateless()->redirect();
```

It is better if you move the `configure` line to `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
// Just right before register SocialiteProvider
$app->configure('services');
$app->register(SocialiteProviders\Manager\ServiceProvider::class);
```

If you have moved this `configure`, your code now should be:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

return Socialite::with('twitter')->stateless()->redirect();
```

PS:

If you have call to undefined `stateless` method, it means you don't set the listener yet, you can read [here](https://socialiteproviders.github.io/providers/twitter/). Open your `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider`, add this line:

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],

        'SocialiteProviders\Manager\SocialiteWasCalled' => [
            'SocialiteProviders\Twitter\TwitterExtendSocialite@handle',
        ]
    ];
}
```

And don't forget to add this line to your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
$app->register(App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class);
```

Comment: Sorry, it does not work. View this response issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132907/8874916

Comment: Do you look at my answer?